# Helix Toolkit - obj submeshes

Tags: c#, helix-3d-toolkit

I am using helix toolkit to import a OBJ file.
The file has a 4 3d models inside.Here is the code i am using to import the OBJ

```cs
Model3DGroup group;
    
ModelVisual3D loadedModel = new ModelVisual3D();
var mi = new ModelImporter();
group = mi.Load("../Model/Vec.3ds");

loadedModel.Content = group;
```

What i am trying to do is select the meshes inside the obj by name.
Names are v_a, v_b,v_c,v_d

I just cant seem the select them.

Comment: The obvious thing here is - does helix have a 3DS importer?  I don't see one here: https://github.com/helix-toolkit/helix-toolkit/tree/master/Source/HelixToolkit.Wpf/Importers Maybe I'm looking in the wrong spot.  Does the OBJ Loader test pass for you?

Comment: I am using a .obj file now and i can count that there are 4children inside the obj, but i just dont know how to select them individually. I want to select them and set the visibility of each item on or off

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the Model3DGroup returned is a standard class:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.media3d.model3dgroup%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Try getting the "collection" by calling Children() on the group, and you should be able to access the models as individual elements of the collection, eg:

```
group.Children().ElementAt(0) 
group.Children().ElementAt(1)
```

Or similar calls.  You should be able to find some examples using Model3DGroup.